# Using ETag in feedparser

Tags: python, django, feedparser

I'm writing a Django view that gets the latest blog posts of a wordpress system.

```
def __get_latest_blog_posts(rss_url, limit=4):
    feed = feedparser.parse(rss_url)
    return something
```

I tried in a terminal to use ETags:

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> d = feedparser.parse("http://a real url")
>>> d.etag
u'"2ca34419a999eae486b5e9fddaa2b2b9"'
>>> d2 = feedparser.parse("http://a real url", d.etag)
```

I'd like to avoid requesting the feed for every user of the web app. maybe etag aren't the best option?
Once the first user sees this view, can I store the etag and use it for all the other users? is there a thread for every user and therefore I can't share the value of a variable this way?

Comment: Eduard, you significantly changed your quesiton, first you asked what is the use of etag, if you cannot use it the first time and you got the answer. Now you are asking, how to preserve some status information for all of your users. You shall create new question.

Answer (score 1):

Etag allows to mark unique status of a web resource, so that you have a chance to ask for the resource expressing latest status you already have.

But to have some version already at your client, you have to fetch it the first time, so for the first request is use of `etag` irrelevant.

See [HTTP Etag at wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), it explains it all.

Typical scenario is:

1. fetch your page the first time and read value of Etag header for future use
2. next time you ask for the same page, you add header `If-None-Match` with value of Etag from your last fetch. Server will check, if there is something new, if the Etag you provide and Etag at current version of resource are the same, it will not return complete page back, but rather returh HTTP Status code `304 Not Modified`. If the page has different status on the server, you get the page with HTTP Status code 200 and with new value of Etag in the response header.

If you want to optimize your app not to generate initial request for the same feed by each user, you shall somehow share the Etag value for given resource globally across your application.

Comment: hi, I updated the part regarding "first time" after reading your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first request the client will never be able to use any local caches, so at the first request ETag isn't necessary. Remember that ETag needs to be passed into the conditional request headers (If-None-Match, If-Match, etc), the semantic of non conditional requests are clear.

If your feed is a public feed, then an intermediate caching proxy are also allowed to return an ETagged result for non conditional request, although it will always have to contact origin server if the conditional header doesn't match.

Comment: hi, I updated the description of the problem after reading your answer

Comment: The origin server are allowed to cache an ETagged results, just like intermediate caching proxies would've done. This can usually be done by having the server store a prerendered result in a Redis/memcached/RDBMS or some such.